# How we Syntax a nested ternary condition in laravel(php)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Here is my ternary condition: how can i syntaxed it.

```
($member_detail->member_type === 'Parent') ? 'Parent Contact' :
       ($member_detail->member_type === 'Adult') ? 'Adult Contact' :
               ($member_detail->member_type === 'Teacher') ? 'Teacher Contact' :
                      ($member_detail->member_type === 'Donor') ? 'Donor Contact' : 'Nothing'
```

Comment: Don't do it! Nested ternary's is one of the bigger code smells you can do.

Comment: That looks like a good candidate for a [`switch` or a `match`](https://stitcher.io/blog/php-8-match-or-switch) in my opinion, but otherwise I think an `if/elseif` would be the best.